# Proof that gradient of $\det(A)$ with respect to $A$ is $\det(A) A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

How to prove that $\dfrac{\partial |A|}{\partial A} = |A|A^{-1}$

where $|A|$ is $\det(A)$ and $A$ is symmetric matrix?

Comment: You could expand $\det(A+H)$, write it as : $\det(A) + L(H) + o(\Vert H \Vert)$ where $L$ is some linear map. The gradient of $\det$ is the only matrix $\nabla_{A}\det \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $L(H) = \left\langle \nabla_{A}\det,H \right\rangle$ (where $\left\langle \cdot,\cdot \right\rangle$ is the usual inner product on $\mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$...)

Comment: Hint: Laplace development of hte determinant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Laplace formula,
$$\det(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+j} a_{ij}M_{ij}$$

Since $A$ is symmetric,
$$\det(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+j} a_{ji}M_{ij}$$

we have
$$\frac{\partial \det(A)}{\partial a_{ji}} = (-1)^{i+j}M_{ij} = [\text{adj}(A)]_{ji}$$

and therefore
$$\frac{\partial \det(A)}{\partial A} = \text{adj}(A) = \det(A)A^{-1}$$